# Ajax loader is not getting called in a file upload custom component in JSF 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, custom-component

In my current project I am trying to create a file upload custom component because we have a constraint that we can’t use any component library. Our requirement is to create single file upload, upon selecting and uploading a file it will get displayed in a data table below that component. User will be able to download the uploaded file and if required can delete the uploaded file also. There will be a ajax loader which needs to be fired upon uploading a file. Pictorially the UI looks like this.

```
 ________________________ __________  ____________
|                       | | Browse  | | Upload    |
|_______________________| |_________| |___________|

______________________________________________
|                                      |      |
|  File1.pdf                            |  *  |
|_______________________________________|_____|
|                                       |     |
|   File2.pdf                           |  *  |
|_______________________________________|_____|
```

To create this component I have taken help from Core JavaServer Pages(3e) to create custom component & BalusC’s blogs to trigger ajax call from a jsf page(jsf.ajax.addOnEvent). Here is the entire code of Renderer, xhtml, and managedbean. For the time being I have used a h:outputtext instead of h:datatable to update the page.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:corejsf="http://corejsf.com">
     <h:head>
    <title>A file upload test</title>
        <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/>
        <script>
             jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
                var ajaxstatus = data.status; 
                var ajaxloader = document.getElementById("ajaxloader");

                switch (ajaxstatus) {
                case "begin": // This is called right before ajax request is been sent.
                    ajaxloader.style.display = 'block';
                    break;

                case "complete":
                    ajaxloader.style.display = 'none';
                    break;

                case "success":                 // NOOP.
                     break;
             } });
    </script>
      </h:head>
      <h:body>
       <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="hello"></h:commandButton>
       </h:form>
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
              Upload a photo of yourself: 
              <corejsf:upload uploadButton="upload"/>
              <h:outputText id="updateText" value="#{user.value}"></h:outputText>
            <h:commandButton action="#{user.submit}" value="Initiate"></h:commandButton>
             </h:form>
                <img id="ajaxloader" src="ajax-loader.gif" style="display: none;" />
        </h:body>
     </html>
```

The Renderer:

```
  package com.corejsf;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
  import java.util.Map;

  import javax.el.ELContext;
  import javax.el.ValueExpression;
  import javax.faces.FacesException;
  import javax.faces.application.ResourceDependencies;
  import javax.faces.application.ResourceDependency;
  import javax.faces.component.EditableValueHolder;
  import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
  import javax.faces.component.UIForm;
  import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
  import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
  import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;
  import javax.faces.render.FacesRenderer;
  import javax.faces.render.Renderer;
  import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;

  @FacesRenderer(componentFamily="javax.faces.Input",
      rendererType="com.corejsf.Upload")
   public class UploadRenderer extends Renderer {
        public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)  
            throws IOException {
         if (!component.isRendered()) return;
         ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
         String ajax = "jsf.ajax.request(this, event,{render:'j_idt11:updateText'}); return false";
         String clientId = component.getClientId(context);
         System.out.println("parentid>>>>>>"+component.getParent().getClientId(context));
         System.out.println(clientId);
         System.out.println("upload button >>>>>>"+(String)component.getAttributes().get("uploadButton"));
          writer.startElement("input", component);
         writer.writeAttribute("type", "file", "type");
         writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId+":INPUT_FILE", "clientId");
         writer.endElement("input");
         writer.startElement("input", component);
         writer.writeAttribute("type", "submit", null);
         writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId + ":FILE_UPLOAD", null);
         writer.writeAttribute("value", "Upload", "value");
         writer.writeAttribute("onclick", ajax, null);
         writer.endElement("input");
         writer.flush();
    }

    public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {



   Map<String,String> requestMap = context.getExternalContext ().getRequestParameterMap();
   String clientId = component.getClientId(context);
   System.out.println("getId>>>>>>>"+component.getId());
   if(requestMap.containsKey(clientId+":FILE_UPLOAD")){

       try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       System.out.println("true");
       ExternalContext external = context.getExternalContext();
       HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) external.getRequest();
       //String clientIdFile = component.getClientId(context);
       FileItem item = (FileItem) request.getAttribute(clientId+":INPUT_FILE");
       System.out.println("filename>>>>"+item.getName()+">>>");
       System.out.println("file blank>>>>"+item.getName().equals(""));
       ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
        UserBean userBean = (UserBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
        .getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "user");
        try {
            userBean.setUploadedFile(item.getInputStream());
            userBean.setValue(userBean.getUploadedFileList().size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
   else
       System.out.println("false");
     }   
  }
```

Managed bean:

```
  package com.corejsf;

  import java.io.Serializable;

  import javax.el.ELContext;
  import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
  //import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
  import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
  import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
  import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
  import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  @ManagedBean(name="user")
  @ViewScoped
  public class UserBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String id;
private ArrayList<InputStream> uploadedFileList = new ArrayList<InputStream>();

public ArrayList<InputStream> getUploadedFileList() {
    return uploadedFileList;
}
public void setUploadedFileList(ArrayList<InputStream> uploadedFileList) {
    this.uploadedFileList = uploadedFileList;
}
private int value = 0;

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public String getId() { return id; }
public void setId(String newValue) { id = newValue; }

public void setUploadedFile(InputStream inputStream){
    uploadedFileList.add(inputStream);
}
  }
```

UploadFilter:

```
   package com.corejsf;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.Enumeration;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Map;
   import javax.servlet.Filter;
   import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
   import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

    public class UploadFilter implements Filter {
        private int sizeThreshold = -1;
        private String repositoryPath;

        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
           repositoryPath = config.getInitParameter(
              "com.corejsf.UploadFilter.repositoryPath");
           try {
           String paramValue = config.getInitParameter(
               "com.corejsf.UploadFilter.sizeThreshold");
           if (paramValue != null) 
               sizeThreshold = Integer.parseInt(paramValue);
           }
           catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
               ServletException servletEx = new ServletException();
               servletEx.initCause(ex);
               throw servletEx;
           }
        }

         public void destroy() {
         }

 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
  ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
  throws IOException, ServletException {

  if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
     return;
  }

  HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

  boolean isMultipartContent 
     = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(httpRequest);
  if (!isMultipartContent) {
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
     return;
  }

  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
  if (sizeThreshold >= 0)
     factory.setSizeThreshold(sizeThreshold);
  if (repositoryPath != null) 
     factory.setRepository(new File(repositoryPath));
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

  try {
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<FileItem> items 
        = (List<FileItem>) upload.parseRequest(httpRequest);
     final Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
     for (FileItem item : items) {
        String str = item.getString();
        if (item.isFormField())
           map.put(item.getFieldName(), new String[] { str });
        else
           httpRequest.setAttribute(item.getFieldName(), item);
     }

     chain.doFilter(new 
        HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpRequest) {
           public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
              return map;
           }                   
           // busywork follows ... should have been part of the wrapper
           public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
              Map<String, String[]> map = getParameterMap();
              return (String[]) map.get(name);
           }
           public String getParameter(String name) {
              String[] params = getParameterValues(name);
              if (params == null) return null;
              return params[0];
           }
           public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
              Map<String, String[]> map = getParameterMap();
              return Collections.enumeration(map.keySet());
           }
        }, response);
  } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
     ServletException servletEx = new ServletException();
     servletEx.initCause(ex);
     throw servletEx;
  }      
 }   
}
```

taglib.xml:

```
<facelet-taglib version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <namespace>http://corejsf.com</namespace>
    <tag>
       <tag-name>upload</tag-name>
       <component>
           <component-type>javax.faces.Input</component-type>
           <renderer-type>com.corejsf.Upload</renderer-type>
       </component>
    </tag>
 </facelet-taglib>
```

The issue that I am facing with this code is that the ajax is updating the h:outputtext but the ajax loader is not working. It is not getting displayed upon uploading a file. It should get displayed on begin status and disappear on complete status. Besides, firefox error console shows a “Reference error: jsf is not defined” message.

I have put a :

```
<h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/>
```

inside h:head tag . But it did not help. The webpage is not responding after adding this line in firefox but it is working on IE, though ajax loader is not working in any case.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.